# LINQ syntax to take all rows except the first one?

Tags: .net, linq

What's the LINQ syntax to take all rows except the first one? Does LINQ offer a nice concise way to do it?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
var allButTheFirst = collection.Skip(1);
```

More info:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358985.aspx

Comment: I originally had it lowercased, which could have been interpreted as "all butt he first". a little judicious camelcasing clears that up... :)

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [Skip(TSource)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358985.aspx) extension method on any IEnumerable.

```
var allButFirst = rows.Skip(1);
```